# php: post on Facebook page using FB apis are visible only to admin

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to post to FB page using FB apis. Post goes through fine but it's visible only to admin user & not everyone who has liked the page. I tried changing privacy settings with EVERYONE & ALL_FRIENDS but it didnt help much. Below is snippet of my code.

Any help is truly appreciated.

```
//--------code snippet------------

require '../src/facebook.php';


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'secret' => 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
            ));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) 
{
    try {
        $page_id = 'ZZZZZZZZZZZ';
        $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
        if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) 
        {
            $args = array(
                'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
                'message'       => "My Msgs!"
            );
            $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
            if( !array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) || 
                !array_key_exists('manage_pages', $permissions['data'][0])) 
            {
                $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream, manage_pages"));
                echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login1 with FB</a>';
            }
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
{
    echo "error ", $e;
}
}

if ($user)
{
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else 
{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
    echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login2 with FB</a>';
}
```

Comment: somebody please help. I am stuck on this one. tried multiple approaches like playing with privacy settings, tried different settings options for the page & also for the FB application. But it just keeps the post visible to only admin.

Comment: Got it after quite long time. My app was running in sandbox mode. Disabled the sandbox mode and evreyone started seeing messages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your app is set in development mode, you need to switch it to public under https://developers.facebook.com -> My Apps -> Select your app -> Status & Review -> Do you want to make this app and its all features available to general public? -> switch to YES